# Why does my html flex code only work in some broswers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have tried implementing HTML flex boxes in my website and while the page works as expected in my desktop browser, on my tablet browser it does not. The page consists for 2 flex rows, header and content. The header div has a height that is based on the content inside it. The content div has a height that is determined the header height from the total page height. The content div is set to overflow scroll.

In my desktop browser, when there is too much content in the 'content' flex row to be displayed at once, the div becomes scrollable. However in my tablet browser, the flex row expands its height to become big enough to contain all of its content.

**Desktop Browser**: Google Chrome (Version 44.0.2403.157), Safari (Version 8.0.2 (10600.2.5))
**Mobile Browser**: Google Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.18)

**My code**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
}


.box .row {
  flex: 0 1 30px;
    border: 2px solid;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrapper" style="height: 100%">
<div class="box">
<div class="row header">
Header - The height of the header is based on the content
</div> <!-- end of flex row header -->
<div class="row content">
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>
Content - The height of the content row is the total broswer height minus the header height
<br>
<br>
<br>

</div> <!-- end of flex row content -->
</div> <!-- end of flex box -->
</div> <!-- end of page wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing the prefixes in your code examples. [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox some iOS Chrome and Safari versions require the `-webkit-` prefix when using flexbox properties. Have you tried this?

Comment: I was not aware that I needed to add prefixes, would you be able to answer, with all of the required prefixes,  to make the website compatible with as many browsers as possible? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The browser versions you are working with have no problems with Flexbox. They do not need any prefixes either. I don't know why others are saying there are issues when even their links show there aren't. Are you using a doctype? Which one?

Comment: In addition to the prefixes, checkout @Marcelo's link and known issue #3.

Answer (score 2):

Because not all browsers support [flex](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) or all features of `flex` and [other measures like prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility) maybe be required to add support. Make sure to check the *Known Issues* tab from [`caniuse.com#feat=flexbox`](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

`CSS Flexible Box Layout Module Level 1` is currently in [Last Call Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) since May 14th, 2015.

Comment: The browser versions he lists work fine with Flexbox.

Comment: @Rob No, Safari still needs the `-web-kit` prefix even on version 8. And according to the documentation (known issues - see Chrome bug): `In Chrome and Safari, the height of (non flex) children are not recognized in percentages. However Firefox and IE recognize and scale the children based on percentage heights.` He's using percentages.

Comment: Look again. It's listed as a requirement.

Comment: You're right. I missed the yellow tag. However, it works in every other browser he listed.

Comment: It does, except he's using percentages for heights, which is listed as a Chrome Bug for not working correctly.

Comment: I tried adding the following prefixes: "  display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;". This did not affect the way that the page appeared in the desktop browser, however it resulted in the mobile browser loading the two flex rows as columns. Each column was 50% of the page width. I tried adding "width: 100%;" to each of the rows, however this did not alter the appearance in the mobile browsers. With the new prefixes the "overflow: scroll" now works as intended.